# Register form in application

Tags: ios, swift

So I have register form in my application, but a problem. Here is my code:

```
@IBAction func registerButtonAction(sender: AnyObject) {
        if (fullnameTextField.text == ""){
            self.fullnameTextField.shake()
        }
        if (usernameTextfield.text == ""){
            self.usernameTextfield.shake()
        }
        if (usernameTextfield.text?.characters.count < 6){
            usernameTextfield.shake()
        }
        if (emailTextfield.text == ""){
            self.emailTextfield.shake()
        }
        if (passwordTextfield.text == ""){
            self.passwordTextfield.shake()
        }
        if (retypepasswordTextfield.text == ""){
            self.retypepasswordTextfield.shake()
        }
        else{
            registerButton.setTitle("Registering user...", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
            registerButton.alpha = 0.20
            registerButton.enabled = false
            registerUser()
        }
    }
```

First: Can I make this code smaller, on easier? And second, I want the user only to start `registerUser()` if all UITextField has text, and `usernameTextField` and `passwordTextField` has character count over 6. Also how to fix that `passwordTextField` and `retypepasswordTextfield` has same text before register? Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bit better in my opinion:

```
@IBAction func registerButtonAction(sender: AnyObject) {
    let validInput = true
    let allTextFields = [fullnameTextField, usernameTextfield, emailTextfield, passwordTextfield, retypepasswordTextfield]
    for textField in allTextFields {
        if textField.text == "" {
            validInput = false
            textField.shake()
        }
    }

    let theTextFieldsWithMin6Characters = [usernameTextfield, passwordTextfield]
    for textField in theTextFieldsWithMin6Characters {
        if textField.text?.characters.count < 6 {
            validInput = false
            textField.shake()
        }
    }
    if passwordTextfield.text != retypepasswordTextfield.text {
        validInput = false
        retypepasswordTextfield.shake()
    }

    if validInput {
        registerButton.setTitle("Registering user...", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        registerButton.alpha = 0.20
        registerButton.enabled = false
        registerUser()
    }
}
```

Comment: The `retypepasswordTextfield ` is shaking all the time now, even if the text is same as password and over 6 characters..

Comment: Looks like Erik Auranaune fixed it! Thanks you guys :)